# su - user doesn't work for users without a password

Tags: users, root, authentication, su

I've created a user on CentOS with `useradd -M username`. Now, I want to become that user just like `su - username`.

It asks me for a password for that user but I didn't set a password for that user. As a workaround, I have to become root then `su - username` works obviously.

First, I thought it asks for a root password but it is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: You're familiar with `sudo`, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After creating the account with the command `useradd` you need to run the following command as root to set a password for this newly created account:

```
$ passwd <username>
```

#### Sudo

If you're absolutely positive that you, (userZ), want to become another user (userX) without providing userX's password, *AND* you don't want to have to become root first then you're likely looking for `sudo`.

The CentOS Wiki does a very good job of covering this entire topic that you're asking about here in this articled titled: [How To Become Root](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot).

Here's a synopsis.

1. You want the ability to do anything as root, such as, becoming other users, without providing their password. Add the following rule to your sudoers file, `/etc/sudoers`. **NOTE:** You edit the sudoers file using the command `visudo` as root!

   ```
   userZ    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
   ```

   The above approach will still challenge you for userZ's password. You can get rid of this protection by adding this rule to sudoers instead.

   ```
   userZ ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
2. You want to parcel out the ability to *only* become a specific user using `sudo`.

   ```
   userZ ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - userX
   ```

   **NOTE:** The above can also be done so that userZ has to use their password to run the `su` command too. The above only let's userZ become userX, nothing more.

Comment: yes i usually do but is it really necessary to accomplish what I am trying to do? thanks.

Comment: @fcukinyahoo - I don't understand your Q then. You always have to create a password for a user account. If it's a system account you're creating then you likely don't need the `-` since the account typically doesn't have a home directory that would need to have dot files sourced as part of the `su`.

Comment: I tried `userZ ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - userX`, and then as `userZ`, I ran `su - userX` (both users exist).  But it still prompted for password.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> It asks me for a password for that user

That's how it works.  If you're not root, you can't assume another user's identity without their password.

If CentOS comes with sudo installed you could add

```
youruserid ALL = (username) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

with `visudo` and then `sudo -u username bash` is like `su - username`

(edit: tried to type sudo specs w/o checking)